# Detecting Erroneous Corrections

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

A block code $C$, with minimum distance $d$ can be used to:

1. Detect $d - 1$ errors
2. Correct $\lfloor\frac{d - 1}{2}\rfloor$ errors

However, the above usually assumes that the number of errors that are introduced is below the correctable / detectable threshold.

Suppose codeword $x$ is transmitted with $k > \lfloor\frac{d - 1}{2}\rfloor$ errors to get $x'$. $C$ is able to detect correctly that an error has occurred in $x'$, but it will erroneously correct the codeword to some $y \neq x$.

Are there any ways to detect erroneous corrections?

Comment: The issue is that if there are two codewords at a distance of $d$, say $x_1$ and $x_2$, then it is impossible to tell for sure if $x_1$ was transmitted with an error of $k$, or if $x_2$ was transmitted with an error of $d-k$, which makes such detection impossible. If you have channel statistics, then you can analyse the probability of incorrect decoding. Alternatively, $d$ can be picked keeping this in mind: approximate the channel statistics, and set $d$ so that the chance of making $>d/2$ errors is acceptably small.

Answer (score 1):

> However, the above usually assumes that the number of errors that are introduced is below the correctable / detectable threshold.

No, the above does not assumes anything. Precisely, it gives the correctable / detectable threshold.

If that threshold is exceeded, then undetected errors can occur (if dealing with detection) or erroneous corrections can happen (if dealing with correction). You cannot (in general) "detect erroneous corrections", if that were possible then we'd never bet on an erroneous correction